# DataSource for the location in google fit Rest API

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-api

What is the data source for location in the google fit rest API? I'm not able to find any data sources for location. I want to access the location from the google fit application. Does anybody know how can I access a datasourceID for location?

I used the following get request to find the list of data sources. I'm not able to find any relevant dataSourceID for location. Please suggest what to do

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources
```

Comment: According to the docs: "Note: This data can only be read by the app that wrote the data. Your app can only read back data it wrote. It cannot read location sample data written by other apps". Source: https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/location#location_sample

Comment: @KeeganTeetaert your comment is correct. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: So it's not possible to get my Google fit application's location? Can you give an example where we can access data?

Comment: @GaneshCKM If you have an application that records fitness data containing a user's location in the Fitness API, than that same application would be able to read the location.

Comment: @KeeganTeetaert I tried tracking workouts where it tracks locations of where we walk and run.But it's not   displaying that as a location Source

Comment: @GaneshCKM "I tried tracking workouts where it tracks locations of where we walk and run" how did you do this? Was your application writing location data itself? If not, it cannot read location data; if it is, your application can only read the data it wrote.

Comment: @AndyTurner No, I understood it wrong. What Keegan told was right. Location has a data source if and only if we create and write the location on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs:

> Note: This data can only be read by the app that wrote the data. Your
> app can only read back data it wrote. It cannot read location sample
> data written by other apps

Source: [developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/location#location_sample](https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/location#location_sample)