# Automatic export location tracks of walking\running activiies in garmin

Tags: geolocation, fitbit, garmin, google-fitness-api

I would like to do some automated export location history - map (or picture of the map) of my walking and running activities from my Garmin watch.
I am not an enterprise developer, so I am not able to use Garmin API.

I am using HealthSync app to sync activities Garmin->GoogleFit.
I am able to see location trak inthe  google fit.
I was trying to retrieve it via GoogleFit API, but looks like google does not allow we to do it :-(  [DataSource for the location in google fit Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66318255/datasource-for-the-location-in-google-fit-rest-api)

I was trying to perform sync Garmin->Fitbit (Fitbit has wonderful API)
But looks like HealthSync is not transferring location tracks from Garmin to Fitbit.

And I am near to giving up :(.
What could be an option for me to automate exporting\saving location tracks of my runs and walking?
I do like my Garmin watch and don't see good alternatives for them. But also I would like to own my data :-)

Answer (score 0):

Google made some policy revisions especially with GDPR regulations tightening their nooses.

As stated in officially published docs, https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/location#location_sample, location data is exclusive to the application that originally wrote it. Thus, it becomes obscured to any other 3P app that also is writing and reading location data of its own.

You can also reach out to their mailing list, fit-developer-support@google.com,  should you need any clarifications with their APIs, especially now that they're introducing Health Connect to replace the Android APIs, https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect